# which command gives error "env: node: No such file or directory"

Tags: node.js, bash, macos, homebrew

I uninstalled Node through Homebrew on macOS and now when I run `which <anything>`, I get this error:

```
env: node: No such file or directory
```

My `$PATH` environment variable is `/Users/ohas/.bin:/Users/ohas/.bin:/Users/ohas/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`.

Any idea what could be causing the error?

Comment: Someone else asked this, and they had a `/usr/local/bin/which` that needed `node` overriding the OS-provided `/usr/bin/which` (which doesn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed Node using the [official installer](https://nodejs.org/en/) and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

On newer macos with readonly /usr/bin, do this instead (assuming node only installed through nvm, not brew):

```
sudo ln -s "$(which node)" /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: can you explain this command in a bit more detail? :) ?